# RSS feeds for other stackexchange pages

Tags: stackexchange

I use

```
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/429540/favorites?body=true
```

to receive information about stackoverflow updates.

I tried to do the same with

```
tex.stackexchange.com
```

and

```
askubuntu.com
```

by modifying the url in the obvious way (replacing stackoverflow) but it does not seem to work. Any idea if and, if yes, how I can receive rss updates for these pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user ID is different on each site:

```
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/tex.stackexchange/users/13403/favorites?body=true
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/users/53910/favorites?body=true
```